# Adicionado vários itens em um DataGrid pelo List<>

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Eu tenho dois textbox. Um para o email e o outro para a observações. Quando o usuario clica no botão adicionar, ele deveria ir adicionando na minha datagrid, mas sem sucesso! Como posso fazer isso? Conforme o usuario vai clicando no botão adicionar, ele tem que ir aumentando as linhas do datagrid

Obs: Utilizo WPF

Estou tentanto da seguinte maneira:

```
public class Email{

     public string email { get; set; }
     public string obs { get; set; }
    }

for (int i=0; i < 10; i++){

     List<Email> lista = new List<Email>();
     Email em = new Email();
     em.email = textEmpEmail.Text;
     em.obs = textEmpObs1.Text;
     lista.Add(em);

     dataGridEmails.ItemsSource = lista;
}
```

Dessa maneira, ele insere 10 de uma vez só... Mas eu precisava que adicionava por click, um de cada vez..

Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Você pode adicionar os valores da seguinte forma.

```
 dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
 dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.Rows.Count-1].Cells[0].Value = textBox1.Text;
 dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.Rows.Count-1].Cells[1].Value = textBox2.Text;
```

Agora caso você queira adicionar a lista toda de uma vez, crie as colunas no seu grid com o "DataPropertyName" igual ao nome das propriedades da sua classe e passe desse jeito.

```
 List<Email> lista = new List<Email>();
 Email em = new Email();
 em.email = textBox1.Text;
 em.obs = textBox2.Text;
 lista.Add(em);

 dataGridView1.DataSource = lista;
```

Comment: Então, mas eu não sei quantas vezes o usuario vai tentar adicionar os email.
Obs: estou utilizado WPF